# rm: cannot remove ...: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I configure kernel-2.6.34.14 in Ubuntu 13.10. When I want to run `make modules_install` one error occured:

```
Warning: you may need to install module-init-tools
See http://www.codemonkey.org.uk/docs/post-halloween-2.6.txt
rm: cannot remove ‘/lib/modules/2.6.34.14/kernel’: Permission denied
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
```

I installed module-init-tools and update and upgrade.

What do I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to be root, try `sudo make modules_install`